# Custom HTML structure in customizer not rendring in Browser

Tags: functions, theme-customizer

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'sutta_section', array(
  'title'    => __( 'Sutta', 'yourtheme' ),
  'priority' => 160,
));

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'show_sutta', array(
  'default'    => true,
  'type'       => 'theme_mod',
  'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'show_sutta', array(
  'label'    => __( 'Show Sutta', 'yourtheme' ),
  'section'  => 'sutta_section',
  'settings' => 'show_sutta',
  'type'     => 'checkbox',
  'input_attrs' => array(
    'class' => 'tgl tgl-light',
    'id' => 'cb1',
  ),
  'label_class' => 'tgl-btn',
)));
```

On the above, I want to deliver a custom HTML structure for Input and label so that I can make some changes in the HTML of the checkbox.

However, in the browser those classes and IDS are still not reflecting →

[image]

Am I using wrong hooks/approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can change in html of customizer control by extend of Class `WP_Customize_Control`
Check this code to change html of checkbox in theme customizer

```
<?php
/**
 * Add customizer function.
 *
 * @param WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize WP_Customize_Manager instance.
 */
function add_customizers_function( $wp_customize ) {

    /**
     * Custom checkbox control class.
     */
    class Checkbox_Custom_Control extends \WP_Customize_Control {
        /**
         * The type of control being rendered.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $type = 'checkbox_custom';

        /**
         * Enqueue our scripts and styles.
         */
        public function enqueue() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-controls-css',  '../css/customizer.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
        }

        /**
         * Render the control in the customizer.
         */
        public function render_content() {
            ?>
            <div class="checkbox_control">
                <?php if ( ! empty( $this->label ) ) : ?>
                    <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( ! empty( $this->description ) ) : ?>
                    <span class="customize-control-description"><?php echo esc_html( $this->description ); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( ! empty( $this->input_attrs['label_class'] ) && ! empty( $this->input_attrs['checkbox_id'] ) &&! empty( $this->input_attrs['checkbox_class'] ) ) : ?>
                    <label class="<?php echo esc_html( $this->input_attrs['label_class'] ); ?>">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="btn_name" id="<?php echo esc_html( $this->input_attrs['checkbox_id'] ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_html( $this->input_attrs['checkbox_class'] ); ?>" <?php $this->link(); ?> <?php checked( $this->value(), true ); ?>/>
                    </label>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }

    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'sutta_section',
        array(
            'title'    => __( 'Sutta', 'text-domain' ),
            'priority' => 160,
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'show_sutta',
        array(
            'default'    => true,
            'type'       => 'theme_mod',
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new Checkbox_Custom_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'show_sutta',
            array(
                'label'         => __( 'Show Sutta', 'text-domain' ),
                'section'       => 'sutta_section',
                'description'   => esc_html__( 'Custom Checkbox description', 'text-domain' ),
                'input_attrs'   => array(
                    'checkbox_id'     => 'cb1',
                    'checkbox_class'  => 'tgl tgl-light',
                    'label_class'     => 'tgl-btn',
                ),
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'add_customizers_function' );
```

You have to make changes in html in Class `Checkbox_Custom_Control` to get your desired structure because I've added different html structure then the default one to show changes more significantly.

Check this image :
[Theme Customizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7KmX.png)

Currently this code is in my active themes' function.php & It's working perfectly but if it's not working same as image I attached here then let me in a comment.